# Error: Electron failed to install correctly - shadow-cljs - failed to load module$node_modules$electron$index

Tags: node.js, electron, clojurescript, shadow-cljs

- this error occurs when running electron progam with clojruescript and shadow-cljs
- node version 16
- electron 17 or 19 - both fail
- clojurescript 11.1.4
- shadow-cljs 2.18.0

```bash
shadow-cljs - failed to load module$node_modules$electron$index
SHADOW import error /home/user/programs/Cara-Dune/.shadow-cljs/builds/main/dev/out/cljs-runtime/Cara_Dune.main.js
App threw an error during load
Error: Electron failed to install correctly, please delete node_modules/electron and try installing again
    at Object.shadow$provide.module$node_modules$electron$index (/home/user/programs/Cara-Dune/.shadow-cljs/builds/main/dev/out/cljs-runtime/node_modules/electron/index.js:19:15)
    at Object.shadow.js.jsRequire (/home/user/programs/Cara-Dune/.shadow-cljs/builds/main/dev/out/cljs-runtime/shadow/js.js:66:18)
    at Object.shadow.js.require (/home/user/programs/Cara-Dune/.shadow-cljs/builds/main/dev/out/cljs-runtime/shadow/js.js:113:20)
    at /home/user/programs/Cara-Dune/.shadow-cljs/builds/main/dev/out/cljs-runtime/Cara_Dune.main.js:5:50
    at global.SHADOW_IMPORT (/home/user/programs/Cara-Dune/out/jar/main.js:64:44)
    at /home/user/programs/Cara-Dune/out/jar/main.js:1607:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/programs/Cara-Dune/out/jar/main.js:1610:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1116:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1169:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Electron failed to install correctly, please delete node_modules/electron and try installing again
    at Object.shadow$provide.module$node_modules$electron$index (/home/user/programs/Cara-Dune/.shadow-cljs/builds/main/dev/out/cljs-runtime/node_modules/electron/index.js:19:15)
    at Object.shadow.js.jsRequire (/home/user/programs/Cara-Dune/.shadow-cljs/builds/main/dev/out/cljs-runtime/shadow/js.js:66:18)
    at Object.shadow.js.require (/home/user/programs/Cara-Dune/.shadow-cljs/builds/main/dev/out/cljs-runtime/shadow/js.js:113:20)
    at /home/user/programs/Cara-Dune/.shadow-cljs/builds/main/dev/out/cljs-runtime/Cara_Dune.main.js:5:50
    at global.SHADOW_IMPORT (/home/user/programs/Cara-Dune/out/jar/main.js:64:44)
    at /home/user/programs/Cara-Dune/out/jar/main.js:1607:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/programs/Cara-Dune/out/jar/main.js:1610:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1116:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1169:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
shadow-cljs - #8 ready!
[401568:0528/134352.966983:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(377)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
^C/home/user/programs/Cara-Dune/node_modules/electron/dist/electron exited with signal SIGINT
```

cannot start program with npx electron main.js - how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

- resolved

```clj
; error when using shadow-cljs for require

(:require ["electron" :as electron])

; works

(defonce electron (js/require "electron"))
```